# Github how to push Xcode project without old files and folders?

Tags: xcode, git, github

I finished an Xcode project and pushed it to github from Xcode 'Source Control' Menu. Then I changed the project name CountryBook to Countries. I Built project and ran. Everything was okay. Then I coiped project folder to desktop as a backup. Then pushed project again. Everything has messed up. Some old named folders and files still exist in repo. Then I deleted every directory and file from github repository. Now, backup version of project is working. But when I try to push it to repo, old files are still exist. I deleted 'origin' from 'Remotes' and created a new repo named 'Countries'. I pushed project again but it was same. A mixed version of old files and new files. When I clone the github version of project, of course it is not runnable. What sould I do and how can I push clean version of my project? I don't want to lose project.

This is Countries repo now:
[image]

This is my working project folder with correct content:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would fix it via command line, lets assume you start from scratch:

**Step 1 - prepare the working branch:**

- Clone the project
- Navigate to root folder of the project
- Checkout the main branch ("main", "master", or whatever it is)
- Create a new branch you will be working with

```
git clone https://github.com/yourorg/yourrepo
cd yourrepo
git checkout main # or master
git checkout -b fixprojectstructure # branch name can be anything
```

**Step 2 - clean project locally**

- Delete old project, old workspace, ensure the names in Podfile and Podfile.lock are fine
- Build the project and ensure it's working

**Step 3 - commit your changes**:

```
# assuming you are in the root of the project
git add .
git commit -m "Some explanation"
```

**Step 4 - push your changes**:

I usually do it the lazy way: just run `git push`, which will show you the proper syntax to push remotely, something like

```
> git push
fatal: The current branch fixprojectstructure has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin fixprojectstructure

> git push --set-upstream origin fixprojectstructure
Enumerating objects: ...
...
remote: Create a pull request for 'fixprojectstructure' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/.../pull/new/fixprojectstructure
remote: 
...
Branch 'fixprojectstructure' set up to track remote branch 'fixprojectstructure' from 'origin'.
```

**Step 5 - merge your changes**:

Basically just do what the line above is saying:

- Navigate to https://github.com/.../pull/new/fixprojectstructure
- Create pull request
- Merge pull request to main (or whatever the initial branch was)

**Note on the side**: configure the `gitignore` file properly for your repo as well. For starters, follow the [gitignore template](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/xcode,swift,cocoapods) to create a proper gitignore file, and then change it the way you need to.

For instance:

- Usually, if you use cocoapods, you do not store `.workspace` folder and its contents in the repo. Instead it's generated using `pod install` command on each machine that needs it.
- It's also common to exclude `Pods` directory from storing in the repo, although there are pro / cons arguments both ways.